# Reciprocity in python igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I am using python igraph and I want to find the reciprocity of the graph. The edge sequence is as follows:

`(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(0, 2)
(2, 0)`

The `g.reciprocity()` function returns 0. I also tried `g.reciprocity(mode="ratio")`

Answer (score 0):

I just created the same graph as your and I got the g.reciprocity().

example:

```
from igraph import *


 g=Graph()
 g.add_vertices(3)
 g.add_edges([(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(2,0)])

rec = g.reciprocity()
print(rec)
```

the results is: 1.0

I am using igraph 0.7.1 version.
You can check your version using:

```
print igraph.__version__
```

Note that the class is: **reciprocity(ignore_loops=True, mode="default")**

So try using: reciprocity(mode="default") or reciprocity(ignore_loops=True, mode="default")